# Find shortest path from array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I have array of objects like

```
const obs = [
    { from: "A", to: "C", dis: 5},
    { from: "A", to: "D", dis: 4},
    { from: "D", to: "C", dis: 8},
    { from: "C", to: "B", dis: 9},
    { from: "B", to: "D", dis: 17},
]
```

Now i have to find shortest path `dis` from A to B.
So fr i have create distance matrix of 2d array

```
findUniqueEndPoints() {

        let _endPoints = []
        obs.forEach(e => {
            if (!_endPoints.includes(e.from)) {
                _endPoints.push(e.from)
            }
            if (!_endPoints.includes(e.to)) {
                _endPoints.push(e.to)
            }

        })
        return _endPoints
    }

    this.endPoints = this.findUniqueEndPoints()
    let _matrix = []
    this.endPoints.forEach((e, i) => {
        //const valus = obs.map(o => o.from === e ? o.dis : null)
       _matrix[i] = this.endPoints.map(() => 0)
   })

   obs.forEach(e => {
       _matrix[this.endPoints.indexOf(e.from)][this.endPoints.indexOf(e.to)] = e.dis
   })
   console.log(_matrix)
  // logs
  //[[0, 5, 4, 0][0, 0, 0, 9][0, 8, 0, 0][0, 0, 17, 0]]
```

Comment: Cool, how are you doing so far? What have you tried?

Comment: _Now i have to find shortest path dis from A to B._ ok, what is your question?

Comment: @bub please check i have update the question.

Comment: Still there is no question

Comment: @bub sorry, my question is how can i find shortest path `dis` from given array of object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the djikstra pathfinding-like logic, build a map of steps to each point while keeping track of the path to it:

```js
var obs = [
    { from: "A", to: "C", dis: 5 },
    { from: "A", to: "D", dis: 4 },
    { from: "D", to: "C", dis: 8 },
    { from: "C", to: "B", dis: 9 },
    { from: "B", to: "D", dis: 17 },
];
function findPath(from, to) {
    var open = obs
        .filter(function (part) {
        return part.from == from || part.to == from;
    });
    var dict = {};
    dict[from] = { dis: 0, path: from };
    obs
        .filter(function (part) {
        return part.from == from || part.to == from;
    })
        .forEach(function (v, i) {
        if (dict[v.to] === void 0) {
            dict[v.to] = { dis: v.dis, path: from + v.to };
        }
        else if (dict[v.to].dis > v.dis) {
            dict[v.to] = { dis: v.dis, path: from + v.to };
        }
    });
    while (dict[to] === void 0) {
        for (var key in dict) {
            if (dict.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var closed = dict[key];
                obs
                    .filter(function (part) {
                    return part.from == key || part.to == key || part.from == key || part.to == key;
                })
                    .forEach(function (v, i) {
                    var c = v.dis + closed.dis;
                    if (dict[v.to] === void 0) {
                        dict[v.to] = { dis: c, path: closed.path + v.to };
                    }
                    else if (dict[v.to].dis > c) {
                        dict[v.to] = { dis: c, path: closed.path + v.to };
                    }
                    if (dict[v.from] === void 0) {
                        dict[v.from] = { dis: c, path: closed.path + v.to };
                    }
                    else if (dict[v.from].dis > c) {
                        dict[v.from] = { dis: c, path: closed.path + v.to };
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    return dict[to];
}
//TEST
var path = findPath("A", "B");
console.log(path);
```